# How to cache mongodb on one server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, redis, microservices

I'm building the api using nodejs and mongoose, and my plan is to install the api on 3 different servers but using the same database. do you think the system cache provided by mongodb can work?

i want to run 3 different api but use 1 database and 1 cache system.

Comment: Not quite sure about what you try to achieve, but are you talking about horizontal scaling of your backend? MongoDB shouldn't care about multiple clients at the same time, so this wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Yes. i am talking about horizontal scaling of my backend. but what I'm questioning is the cache feature of mongodb, is it still working or not?